# Peticion POST con Encabezado multipart/form-data con angular 4

Tags: http, angular

Al intentar realizar una petición `POST` al servidor con angular 4, retorna error, ya he intentado un millón de cosas y nada, he investigado y nada.

```
this.http.post('localhost:53286/api/Home/Signup', formData, options).suscribe(
           res>=>{}
           err=>{}
)
```

Ese es mi metodo para hacer el post al servidor

```
 let options : RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();  
 options.header.append({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'});
```

Al realizar la petición me devuelve error 500, llevo ya días con este error, quizá afecte la manera en la que subo el archivo y es de esta forma. teniendo el `@ViewChild('fileInput') FileInput;`

```
Upload(){
     let FileBrowser = this.FileInput.NativeElement;
     if(FileBrowser.files && FileBrowser.files[0])
       this.signupmodel.CIPath = FileBrowser.files[0];
  }
```

Siendo el `signupmodel.CIPath` donde se guarda la dirección de la imagen.

Comment: error 500 no es que esta mal tu subida de archivo, es error del servidor deberias ver el log a ver donde esta!

Comment: pueden ser permisos de escritura en tu servidor, el archivo no cumple el formato

Comment: Pero cual deberia ser el formato??

Comment: por lo que veo en el codigo se ve muy bien , debes verificar tu backend a ver que esta fallando

Answer (score 1):

Para subir ficheros con Angular, lo mejor es que utilices el XHR en vez del servicio HTTP de Angular 2/4 ya que no va muy bien en este aspecto...

#### He preparado una función en TypeScript para utilizar XHR cómodamente:

```
export const xhr = (
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE' | 'OPTIONS' = 'GET',
    url: string,
    headers: { [key: string]: any },
    body = null,
    files: File[] = []
): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        const params = body !== null ? body : {};
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('files[]', files[i], files[i].name);
        }
        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => formData.append(key, params[key]));
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (req.readyState === 4) {
                if (req.status >= 200 && req.status <= 299) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(req.response));
                } else {
                    reject(req.response);
                }
            }
        };
        req.onerror = () => reject(null);
        req.onabort = () => reject(null);
        req.open(method, url, true);
        Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => req.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]));
        req.send(formData);
    });
};
```

#### Ejemplo de uso:

```
const file = ...; // Tu fichero
xhr('POST', `${env.baseUrl}/upload/file`, {
            'Authorization': this.authService.bearerToken(),
            'Accept': 'application/json' }, { name, date }, [file])
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

---

Si continúas teniendo el error 500 qué es de Servidor, ya no es porque envíes mal los datos, si no porque en tu servidor los trata mal.